# How do you make a custom PCB footprint?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, components

I’m new to PCB making so bear with me. I’m making a board for a machine I’m working on. It uses a A4988 stepper motor driver and I can’t find any component I could import to use. I figured I could just design where the holes go on the PCB but I’ve been researching and I’ve found absolutely nothing.

Does anyone know if there’s a component to connect a PCB to a Raspberry Pi, like a bunch of 2.54mm Marwin pins in one design? I’m not sure what they are called. If this is unclear please comment so I can clarify. I’m new and not sure what everything is called.

Edit: When I say I want to know how to make custom PCB components I’m talking about PCB footprints.

I’m using EasyEDA as PCB design software.

Comment: Are you talking about needing a footprint for the A4988, or a 3D model, or something else?

Comment: @Tyler so like when u design a PCB and you import a component to add into your design I want to know how to make my own component that I could import if that makes sense

Comment: That makes more sense, what PCB design tool are you using, the methods are not all the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question to state what CAD software you are using?

Comment: Depends on which tool you are using. Have you tried to read the documtation for it or search online?

Comment: @Tyler I’m using EasyEDA

Comment: As a side not, you should make ALL of your own parts (footprints).  You usually don't realize there is an error in an imported footprint, until it's too late. =D

Comment: Ok and thanks for clarifying that their called footprints

Comment: Well, I would suggest you update your question, all of the relevant information should be in the question (not the comments).

Comment: And I am not familiar with EasyEDA, so someone else will have to help with that.

Comment: @Tyler are you good with eagle? I have that installed don’t have a preference yet

Comment: I am sure there are many folk here who are familiar with EasyEDA.

Comment: Never used easyeda, but this looks promising: https://docs.easyeda.com/en/PCBLib/PCBLib-Create/index.html

Comment: Thank you @user1850479 if u make it an answer I can mark it correct once I try it

Answer (score 0):

This is documentation on how to add custom footprints in easyEDA

https://docs.easyeda.com/en/PCBLib/PCBLib-Create/index.html

Comment: I wonder if this Q/A has some intrinsic value for this stack site. Looking at the title, (and strictly speaking) this doesn't answer the question. Secondly, It is link-only answer.